# BAD_ACCESS when calling CSSearchableIndex indexSearchableItems

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement the CoreSpotlight API in my app but can't seem to figure out why I am getting a BAD_ACCESS exception with my implementation:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet * attributeSet = [CSSearchableItemAttributeSet new];

attributeSet.title = route.Options.name;
attributeSet.keywords = [route.Options.name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_busstop.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
attributeSet.thumbnailData = imageData;

CSSearchableItem * item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:route.ObjectID domainIdentifier:@"com.whatever.itsmyappsname.loadwithroute" attributeSet:attributeSet];

[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item] completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"It worked");
}];
```

Looking at the call stack for the exception, I can see that it occurs on the `CSSearchableIndex indexSearchableItems: completionHandler:` call.  However I can step past that call without the exception triggering, maybe it has to do with the completion handler, however it happens regardless of if I have one or not.  I have `CoreSpotlight/CoreSpotlight.h` and `MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h` imported both in my .h file and in the target.

Comment: Have you tried enabling NSZombies? They often help with figuring out EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're (I'm) creating the CSSearchableItemAttributeSet object incorrectly.  Instead of:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet * attributeSet = [CSSearchableItemAttributeSet new];
```

Use:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet * attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc]
                                                initWithItemContentType:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
```